# Send JS variable to PHP script via ajax on click of button where the href attribute is set dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

This is the current situation:

- I have one checkbox on each row of a table representing some infos
- A button that is initially disabled and if any checkbox is checked it gets enabled
- This button is wrapped/enclosed by an `<a></a>` tag like this `<a><button type="button" id="myId" classes="classes..."></button></a>`
- An array which is initally empty

Suppose I have 10 rows (so 10 checboxes, one for each row) eveytime I check a checkbox I push into the array some info represented inside the table and I enable the disabled button **(even with 1 checkbox the button gets enabled)**

At this point what I want to do on the `click` event of the enabled button is to set the `href` attribute and a link to a PHP file on the `<a>` tag that is wrapping the button and secondly to send via ajax that array which contains info from the table.

I tried to do it this way but it does not seem to work:

```js
 $('#my_initially_disabled_button').on('click',function(){
   if(some_generic_flag == true){
      let link = this.parentNode;
      link.setAttribute('href','scripts/php_script.php');
      
      $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'php_script.php', 
        data: { data: my_array }, // my_array is that array which gets update each time a checkbox is checked
        success: function() {
            //some stuff;
        }
    });
   }
});
```

I also tried to make write the ajax part outside of the on click event but still is not working the result I get is a blank page....

The interesting fact is that if I remove the ajax part it redirects me correctly to the PHP file and correctly echoes stuff.

In the PHP I tried to receive the ajax request like this

```js
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $var = $_POST['data'];
     
     // if I do var_dump($var) it does not work
}
```

Comment: _"This button is wrapped/enclosed by an <a></a> tag like this"_ - that is invalid HTML; `a` and `button` are both "interactive elements", and as such not allowed to be nested.

Comment: What is 'my_array'? Where does it get declared?

Comment: @Wimanicesir I declared it at the starting point of the JS script...through jquery I check if any checkbox gets checked and if so i do array_push() into my_array

Comment: Well we can't see that, it could be 'my_array' is not set. It is hard to find the problem if we can't see the whole picture. Try to look in the networktab if your data is properly sent :)

Comment: Having multiple buttons with `id="my_initially_disabled_button"` is also invalid - `id`s _must_ be unique

Comment: *"but it does not seem to work"* - Can you be more specific about the observed problem?  If you're not familiar with how to use your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  Which specific operation fails or produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  Can you update the question to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  (The AJAX operation would expectedly result in a 404 in such an example, but can still at least demonstrate the working *request*.)

Comment: @twww123 In which page are you redirecting on the click of button??? Can you tell that

Comment: @Developer exactly on the desired page but the data passed to that page is not getting received...for example if I try to print 'my_array' it gives me an my_array is not defined error

Comment: @twww123 Oky, so only data is not going. Right??

Comment: @Developer exactly

Comment: @twww123 I have described it in the answer. Try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove the link from the button - it is invalid and unnecessary.
- grab the checked info when clicking the button

```js
$(function() {
  const $button = $("#send");
  let array = [];
  $("#container").on("input", () => {
    array = $(".info:checked").map(function() {
      return this.value
    }).get();
    $button.prop("disabled", array.length === 0);
  });
  $button.on("click", () => {
    const data = JSON.stringify(array);
    console.log(data)
    // $.ajax(...., data:data, ....)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <label>info1 <input type="checkbox" value="info 1 data" class="info" /></label><br/>
  <label>info2 <input type="checkbox" value="info 2 data" class="info" /></label><br/>
  <label>info3 <input type="checkbox" value="info 3 data" class="info" /></label><br/>
  <button id="send" disabled>Send</button>
</div>
```